# Excel Gantt chart: time line fixed start 1st each month in major steps?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts, gantt

I am using this an excel Gantt chart like this one, to name any: https://www.vertex42.com/Files/download2/themed.php?file=project-task-list-with-gantt-chart.xlsx

No matter what I try, the Gantt chart has always inconsistent start dates at the major steps. I want each major step to start at the first of each month to see like Oct-21, Nov-21, Dec-21.

When I enter start date 1/12/22 for a task, the bar should start at the Dec-21 line.

Any suggestions?

Example image:
[image: Example]

Comment: I have a very long tutorial that shows how to achieve a nice first-of-the-month axis on a Gantt chart: [Gantt Chart with Nice Date Axis](https://peltiertech.com/gantt-chart-nice-date-axis/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chart that is created by the template you've downloaded is a standard Excel Bar Chart.  If you select the horizontal axis and choose the format option, you'll see that it uses the dates as Min/Max bounds.  And the Major Unit is 28 which is the interval you're seeing on your labels-28 days.  There is no direct method to set the major steps to the first of each month because Excel uses the Major Unit value to establish the label intervals-and months (and years) have varying lengths.

There is a work around for adding labels like you're expecting, however it would require that you modify the chart from it's original template settings.

Comment: Thanks! What would that require, exactly?